# How to stop the user from being able to submit all other Django forms once a specific form is submitted?

Tags: python, django, django-templates, cs50

I am trying to create an e-commerce site (CS50 Project 2) that allows its users to make comments, bids, and add listing items to their watchlists. I want the user who created the listing to be able to close the listing so that the winner (highest bidder) is displayed and no other of the forms will work (I also want to delete the listing from the watchlist). Currently, when the user who created the listing closes the listing, it saves (because it is a Django model), but the forms do not disappear, the listing does not delete off the watchlist, and the messages do not appear. How do I fix this?  (I think it has to do with the if statement.)

views.py

```
@login_required(login_url='login')
def listing(request, id):
    #gets listing
    listing = get_object_or_404(Listings.objects, pk=id)
    #code for comment and bid forms
    listing_price = listing.bid
    sellar = listing.user
    comment_obj = Comments.objects.filter(listing=listing)
    #types of forms
    comment_form = CommentForm()
    bid_form = BidsForm()
    #watchlist_form = WatchListForm()
    #closelisting_form = CloseListingForm()
   
    #close listing code
    if sellar == request.user:
        closeListingButton = True
    else: 
        closeListingButton = False
    closeListing = ''
    try:
        has_closed = get_object_or_404(CloseListing, Q(
            user=request.user) & Q(listing=listing))
    except:
        has_closed = False
    if has_closed:
        closeListing = False
    else: 
        closeListing = True
    
   #watchlist code
    add_or_remove_watchlist = ''
    try:
        has_watchlists = get_object_or_404(WatchList, Q(
            user=request.user) & Q(listing=listing))
        print('--------------------------')
        print(has_watchlists)
        print('--------------------------')
    except:
        has_watchlists = False

    if has_watchlists:
        add_or_remove_watchlist = True
    else:
        print('it will from remove')
        add_or_remove_watchlist = False

    #code for the bid form
    bid_obj = Bids.objects.filter(listing=listing)
    other_bids = bid_obj.all()
    max_bid =0
    for bid in other_bids:
        if listing.bid > max_bid:
            max_bid = listing.bid

     #checks if request method is post for all the forms
    if request.method == "POST":
        #forms
        comment_form = CommentForm(request.POST)
        bid_form = BidsForm(request.POST)

        #watchlist code
        if request.POST.get('add'):
            WatchList.objects.create(user=request.user, listing=listing)
            add_or_remove_watchlist = False
        elif request.POST.get('remove'):
            add_or_remove_watchlist = True
            has_watchlists.delete()

        #close listing code
        if request.POST.get('close'):
            CloseListing.objects.create(user=request.user, listings=listing)
            closeListing = True
            closeListingButton = False
        else:
            closeListing = False

        #checks if comment form is valid
        if comment_form.is_valid():
            comment = comment_form.save(commit=False)
            comment.listing = listing
            comment.user = request.user
            comment.save()
        else:
            return redirect('listing', id=id)

        #checks if bid form is valid
        if bid_form.is_valid():
            print("bid form is valid")
            new_bid = bid_form.cleaned_data.get("bid")
            if (new_bid >= listing_price) and (new_bid > max_bid):
                bid = bid_form.save(commit=False)
                bid.listing = listing
                bid.user = request.user
                bid.save()
                print("bid form is saving")
            else:
                print(bid_form.errors)
                print("bid form is not saving")
                return render(request, "auctions/listing.html",{
                    "auction_listing": listing,
                    "form": comment_form,
                    "comments": comment_obj,
                    "bidForm": bid_form,
                    "bids": bid_obj,
                    "message": "Your bid needs to be equal or greater than the listing price and greater than any other bids."
                })
        else:
            print(bid_form.errors)
            return redirect('listing', id=id)

        #what happens if listing is closed
        if closeListing == True:
            closeListingButton = False
            has_watchlists.delete()
            winner = max_bid.user
            return render(request, "auctions/listing.html",{
                        "auction_listing": listing,
                        "comments": comment_obj,
                        "bids": bid_obj,
                        "closeListingButton": closeListingButton,
                        "closeListing": closeListing,
                        "closedMessage": "This listing is closed.",
                        "winner": winner
            })
        else: 
            return redirect('listing', id=id)
       
    return render(request, "auctions/listing.html",{
        "auction_listing": listing,
        "form": comment_form,
        "comments": comment_obj,
        "bidForm": bid_form,
        "bids": bid_obj,
        "watchlist": add_or_remove_watchlist,
        "closeListingButton": closeListingButton
    })

listing.html
```

```
<!--close listing code-->
    {% if closeListing == True %}
        <div>{{ closedMessage }}
            <br>
            {{ winner }} has won the auction!
        </div>
    {% endif %}

    <form action = "{% url 'listing' auction_listing.id %}" method = "POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {% if closeListingButton == True %}
            <input type = "submit" value = "Close Listing" name = "close">
            <br>
            <br>
        {% endif %}

    <!--watchlist form-->
    {% if watchlist_message %}
        <div>{{ watchlist_message }}</div>
    {% endif %}

    <form action = "{% url 'listing' auction_listing.id %}" method = "POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {% if watchlist == True %}
            <input type="submit" value='Remove from Watchlist' name='remove'>
        {% else %}
            <input type="submit" value='Add to Watchlist' name='add'>
        {% endif %}
    </form>

    <br>
    <!--bid form-->
    {% if message %}
        <div>{{ message }}</div>
    {% endif %}

    <form action = "{% url 'listing' auction_listing.id %}" method = "POST" name = "newBid">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ bidForm }}
        {{ bidForm.errors }}
        <input type = "submit" value = "Place Bid">
    </form>
    {{ bidForm.errors }}

    <br>
    {% for bid in bids %}
        <h6>${{ bid.bid }} <div style = "font-family: monospace;">Bid By: {{ bid.user }}</div></h6>
    {% endfor %} 

    <!--comment form-->
    <br>
    <form action = "{% url 'listing' auction_listing.id %}" method = "POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form }}
        <input type = "submit" value = "Add Comment">
    </form>

    <br>
    {% for comment in comments %}
        <h6> {{ comment.comment }} <div style = "font-family: monospace;">Comment By: {{ comment.user }}</div></h6>
    {% endfor %}
```

Comment: @JohnGordon, ```{% if closeListing == True %}``` is not working. Even after the ```closeListingButton``` is pressed the ```closedMessage``` does not appear.

Comment: If the closed message does not appear, then there must be some error that happens in the `try` block.  Remove the try/except statements and un-indent the `has_closed = get_object_or_404(...)` line, so that if an error occurs, it will not be caught, and you can see the error.

Comment: Never use `except` without `Exception` specified, because if something happens that you didn't predict, you will not find error easily.

Comment: @JohnGordon, I fixed the problems with ```has_closed = get_object_or_404(...)```, but the ```closedMessage``` does still not appear. Could something be wrong with my logic?